# How to get specific value from looped element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I looped my html, and wish to get specific field value when the user clicked the button.
I am having headahce to retrieve the correct value please help me out.

```
<div id="tabs1">
<table>
{foreach from=$this->products item=p}               
<tr>
<td><div class="tabs-product">
<div>
<input type='hidden' id='item' name='item' value='{$p.name}'/>
<input type='hidden' id='price' name='price' value='{$p.price}'/>
<button class="shareButton" onclick='post(); return false;'>Share</button>
</div></td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table></div>

<script>
 function post() {
    var item =  $(this).parent("tabs-product").attr("input");//this cause undefined
    var price = $('#price').val(); //this method only get first value
    alert(item + price);
}
</script>
```

Comment: not use `onclick='post()'` with jquery

Comment: Your loop will not keep the `id` unique for elements. which is not good.

Comment: @PankitKapadia not need id I think

Comment: @eicto - `var price = $('#price').val();`. for this. and its just a suggestion. :)

Comment: it will work when `$(this).parent().children('[name=item]').val()` but o'c it would be better to setup class like `name` and do
 `$(this).parent().children('.name');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $product = $(this).closest('.tabs-product');
var item = $product.find('input[name="item"]').val();
var price = $product.find('input[name="price"]').val();
```

- `input` is an element, not an attribute.
- You can't use absolute IDs like in your `$('#price')`, since you have several elements with identical IDs (printed by a loop) - it is both illegal by spec (but permitted by lax browsers), and useless
- Using `input[name="..."]` selector, you can pinpoint which `input` element within the product you actually need.
- In this case, `parent` and `closest` work equally well, but I like `closest` better for the flexibility in these kinds of cases, if you change your mind about the structure and decide to insert an extra element, for layout or whatever other reason. **EDIT**: As noted by TJ in comments, I missed the `<div>`, which just drives this point home.

Comment: `.parent` won't work, because it only travels up one level.

Comment: @TJ.: Oh indeed, I completely missed that `<div>`. Thanks. That makes my argument even stronger... :P Also, it only has the opening tag, it's autoclosed by `</td>` >.<

Comment: @Eric: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywtnp/1/). If you're getting `NaN`, the most probable cause is `item` being `undefined`, which means you're doing something different from me. I'm afraid I don't know what exactly that would be, can't read minds. :p

Comment: @Amandan I tried your method, I had change my ID to Class now. The out put I get from alert dialog is NaN or Undefined if alert one value. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need some basic corrections in the code.

- Bind the `click` event with `jQuery` to get jQuery object by `$(this)`.
- You also need to use . for class selector. In your code `parent("tabs-product")` should be `parent(".tabs-product")`
- div with class tabs-product is not parent of button rather you need to go to parent td and find the item and price.
- id is supposed to be unique in the page and you will have repeated same ids for item and price.

> $('.shareButton').click(function(){
>
> ```
>     var item =  $(this).closest('td').find("#item").va();//undefined
>     var price = $(this).closest('td').find("#price").va()
>     alert(item + price);
> ```
>
> });

To use `javascript onclick binding` as you have in question, you need to pass the source object to post and convert it to jQuery object in `post`.

```
<button class="shareButton" onclick='post(this); return false;'>Share</button>

function post(obj) {
     var item =  $(this).closest('td').find("#item").va();//undefined
    var price = $(this).closest('td').find("#price").va()
    alert(item + price);
}
```

Comment: `parent` only checks the direct parent and there is no attribute `input`.

Comment: Thanks TJ, tried to sort out there are many....

Comment: @Adil I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined `. Another thing is if the ID had change to Class we no longer can use `#item` right?

Comment: Yes you are right for using class instead of id then we will use dot . instead of # .item I could not see toLowerCase in your code? Make sure you call toLowerCase on string not on object

Answer (score -1):

ok as I see your codes, you are doing it wrong. You iterate and you create elements with same ID's which is not really good practice at all. so I recommend you to use `class` attribute and use `Jquery.first()`

```
<div id="tabs1">
<table>
{foreach from=$this->products item=p}               
<tr>
<td><div class="tabs-product">
<div>
<input type='hidden' class='item' name='item' value='{$p.name}'/>
<input type='hidden' class='price' name='price' value='{$p.price}'/>
<button class="shareButton" onclick='post(); return false;'>Share</button>
</div></td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table></div>

<script>
 function post() {
    var item =  $(this).parent("tabs-product").attr("input");//undefined
    var price = $('.price').first().val(); //get only first value
    alert(item + price);
}
</script>
```

well other's answers are ok but having multiple identical ID's is not really good at all especially when using Jquery

`JQuery.first()` reference
http://api.jquery.com/first/

sample usage of `JQuery.first()` here http://jsfiddle.net/uAkE8/2/

Comment: The IDs are only one part of the issue.

Comment: @TJ i'm just giving a suggestion to solve his problem much better than just solving his problem but making his code better. So I suggest the simplest way rather than doing complicated codes

Comment: ok thanks, change id to class